# How can i open a link in php as a popup or modal ?

Tags: php, html

I have images in a database linked to a specific Id $SetID. by clickin on the small image it should rederict me to the larger image in the database, and it does but my only problem is that it open a whole new tab to do so. I want to open the image as small pop up or a modal so that the viewer can close it quickly after seeing the photo. here's my code:

```
print ("<td> <a href='$prefix$imagename'> <img src=\"$prefix$filename\" alt=\"Set $SetID\"/> </a> </td>");
```

$prefix is my link, $imagename is the id to the large pic in the database, $filename is the small pic in the same database (large and small are in diffrent folders but have the same $SetID). 
Thanks !

Comment: i think you can't do that in php

Comment: PHP is server side, it just sends text to the client.  It has no concept of popups or modals.

Comment: But can't i close php, do it in html then reopen php with ?> <?php etc ?

Comment: @MarwanAskar - yes, you can close PHP, do some HTML, and then restart PHP but it wouldn't be any different to what you have now. PHP is **completely** server side - all it does is send HTML to a web browser. What you need is JavaScript on your web page to handle modal/pop-up boxes. Check out jQuery-UI which should help you (other libraries are available)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in PHP, but what you can do is

- create a genearal Javascript function which takes the image url as argument
- within this function open a popup with its content as an image tag with the img url passed in the argument
- in php, when generating the tumbnails add the onlick listener to something like: `onlick="youfunction( 'imglink' )"`